# Altering params in Sinatra before blocks

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am trying to alter the request params in a `before` block in Sinatra.

It seems that when using this syntax, it works:

```
before do
  @params['global-before'] = 'yes'
end
```

But when using this syntax, it does not work:

```
before '/:id/test' do
  @params['route-before'] = 'yes'
end
```

Here is a full example:

```
# test.rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'

set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
set :port, 3000

before do
  @params['global-before'] = 'yes'
end

before '/:id/test' do
  @params['route-before'] = 'yes'
end

get '/' do
  params.to_json
end

get '/:id/test' do
  params.to_json
end
```

Then running:

```
$ ruby test.rb

$ curl localhost:3000
{"global-before":"yes"}

$ curl localhost:3000/123/test
{"global-before":"yes","id":"123"}
```

I was expecting to see the `params['route-before']` populated as well.

I have tried using `request.params` instead of `@params` but that did not work at all.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

#### Update:

Opened an [issue](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/1567) in Sinatra's issue tracker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route filter goes first, and it has route parameters: `{"id"=>"123"}`, so [this](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/b0081892f1ec9f44e9a0bba6fb154f7e9d7bec86/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1022) happens:

```
original, @params = @params, @params.merge(params) if params.any?
```

where `original` ends up as `{}` and `@params` as `{"id"=>"123"}`. When the global filter runs, there are no route parameters, so `original` remains unassigned (`nil`) and `@params` is the `{}` that was originally there.

After the filter processes, in the `ensure` clause, there is [this](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/b0081892f1ec9f44e9a0bba6fb154f7e9d7bec86/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1041):

```
@params = original if original
```

So global filter skips it, because `original` is `nil`, because there were no route parameters. The route filter resets the `@params` to whatever it was before the filter ran, because `original` is preserved, because there were route parameters.

I can't say whether this is a bug or an intended behaviour, but it's a "how" at least, if not a "why". It may make sense asking the [Sinatra team](http://sinatrarb.com/contributing.html) (and reporting back here with the verdict).

tl;dr: `@params` are reset to pre-filter state if there are parameters in the filter's path pattern.

Note: you can hack around it by making your own instance variable:

```
before '/:id/test' do
  @route_before = 'yes'
end

get '/:id/test' do
  "Did we run route before? #{@route_before}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I know I can use my own instance vars, but it is less desirable. This seems like a definite bug to me. I will try to report in the Sinatra repo and report back if there is anything of interest.